# Sorting column with more than one decimal

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort column A values in Excel sheet. 
Ex:

```
1.2
2.1
3.1
1.1.1
1.2.3
```

when I click sort button it should re-arrange.

```
1.2
1.1.1
1.2.3
2.1
3.1
```

I have written a sort code but the code does sort only for single decimal values because its integer when we add more than one dot then excel converts it has String. can you please suggest where I am wrong.

```
Private Sub Sort_Click()
    Dim xlSortA As XlSortOrder
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If (CInt(.Range("A2").Value) > CInt(.Range("A" & CStr(LastRow)))) Then
            xlSortA = xlAscending
        End If

        .Range("A2:D10" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("A2:D10"), Order1:=xlSort, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
     End With

     ActiveWorkbook.Save
  End Sub
```

Note: Based on sort it has to re-arrange the remaining columns as well that is working.

Comment: Format the column to text

Comment: i don't see the use of variable xlSortA.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Be aware that text sorting would sort `1.2.1` **after** `1.10.1`. which might not be what we expect. But there is no sort algorithm built in in Excel that would get this one as we would expect it. So this would not be an easy task to achieve.

Comment: Now a silly question why 1.2 comes before 1.1.1? You could do the sort algorithm via arrays parsing each decimal in it's own column and sorting with prioritizing from beginning to end but to be frank there isn't such a sort algorithm in excel that would place 2 before 1  based on the following amount of decimals so that would be needed to be built on your own. It could be you could use amount of decimals as a prioritize value tho. This sort of result is prolly easier to achieve by just using large tables and worksheet functions first to test the algorithm patterns actually work.

Comment: You should also consider it as a sort of unwritten standard that 1.1.1 is likely considered as subsection to 1.1 and not to 1.2.

Comment: You will need a bespoke rearrange function as your sort list does not conform with it's priorities throughout the sort. i.e. you are currently prioritising the first number then changing the priority to the length of the string before again altering the priority to numerical increments. (This probably comes across as very confusing). Hopefully this will help explain my point: If the length was the first priority then the list should be [1.2, 2.1, 3.1, 1.1.1, 1.2.3]. If numerical incrementation was the first priority then the list should be [1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.3, 2.1, 3.1].

Comment: You could have a reference table, and/or use a helper column.  This would require a hefty formula I'd imagine to do the split, but you could then sort based on this, i.e. 1 is number 1, 2.1.1 is number 2, and 1.2 is number 3.

Answer (score 0):

After split the data of '1.2.3' with "." , and sort the data with three columns in the new sheet.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, Temp As Worksheet
    Dim vSplit, vR(), v
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, i As Long, n As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", "d" & LastRow)
        vDB = rngDB
        r = UBound(vDB, 1)
        c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    End With
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 3)
    Set Temp = Sheets.Add
    With Temp
        .Range("a1").Resize(r, c) = vDB
        For i = 1 To r
            n = 0
            vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 1), ".")
            For Each v In vSplit
                n = n + 1
                vR(i, n) = v
            Next v
        Next i
        .Range("e1").Resize(r, 3) = vR
        .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("e1"), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Range("f1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=.Range("g1"), order3:=xlAscending
        vDB = .Range("a1").Resize(r, c)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```